# Child was casted to parent class, any ways to extract the fields?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, casting

I have a working method to extract the field from a class and its super classes  by string value leveraging `... c.getDeclaredField(field) ...`

Suppose we have

```
public void doSomething(Parent child){

//Not working
helper.getMyField(child,"refId");

//Working
helper.getMyField((Child)child,"refId");

}
```

I know it's because the first call starts searching at a level above, which is above the correct location. But I also don't want to hardcode to cast the class to be `Child` (also omitted `instanceof` if I'm really doing this way).

What if all child classes have the same field name? Even not, the method `getMyField()` can catch the Field Not Found Exception. In other word, I can cast it to any child class to get that field value. The thing is(obviously), one child class can't be casted to another child class.

How to revert the casting or backtrack to avoid using hardcode casting while the child is casted to its parent class in the input?

Comment: Can you share the code of `helper.getField()` ?

Comment: Add the additional method to parent and overwrite it in each child. Parent's implementation could be just `{}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get the actual class of child object by using child.getClass() and then cast this object to needed class inside your method. The getClass() method return the actual class of the object and not the parent class and because of that you don't need to hardcode you cast operation

```
public void doSomething(Parent child){


//Working
helper.getField(child.getClass().cast(child),"refId");

}
```

Maybe it will be helpful